# Crawler to extract only content, excluding photos/ads and etc'

Tags: web, web-crawler

Anyone know a good open source crawler I can use to extract ONLY the page content, meaning only text without photos/ads/menus and etc'?

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the ads look like in the HTML, [Norconex HTTP Collector](http://www.norconex.com/product/collector-http/) can help you do that.  It is a very flexible open-source web crawler.  When you configure its importer module, you can tell it to strip chunks of text before and after certain tags, or strip what's between known tags.

To give you an idea, if you know a certain site displays its ads between these tags:

```
<div class="myAdd">... add here ...</div>
```

Then the relevant importer section would look like:

```
<transformer class="com.norconex.importer.transformer.impl.StripBetweenTransformer"
      inclusive="true">
  <stripBetween>
      <start><![CDATA[<div class="myAdd">]]></start>
      <end><![CDATA[</div>]]></end>
  </stripBetween>
</transformer>
```

You can use the same principle to strip headers and footers.   If you do not want images crawled, you can easily filter them out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Portia from Scrapinghub.com